# How to add spacing between span elements which are wrapped around inside div tag?

Tags: html, css

I have a parent `div` element with multiple `span` elements as it children.
The `span` elements are wrapping to new lines inside the `div` element. But I am trying to add some vertical spacing between `span` on the first row and the 2nd row.
I have tried adding margins as

`margin-bottom: 4px;`

and

`margin: 4px 0px 4px 0px;`

but neither option works.

```
<div style="width: 200px;">
    <span style="border:2px solid red; margin-bottom:4px;"> text 1 </span>
    <span style="border:2px solid red; margin-bottom:4px;"> text 2 </span>
    <span style="border:2px solid red; margin-bottom:4px;"> text 888888 888888 888 888  8  8888 8 8 888 888 8888 888  88888  8888 888 8888 8888 8888 </span>
    <span style="border:2px solid red; margin-bottom:4px;"> text 4 </span>
    <span style="border:2px solid red; margin-bottom:4px;"> text5 </span>
    <span style="border:2px solid red; margin-bottom:4px;"> text 6 </span>
    <span style="border:2px solid red; margin-bottom:4px;"> text 7 </span>
    <span style="border:2px solid red; margin-bottom:4px;"> text 9 </span>
    <span style="border:2px solid red; margin-bottom:4px;"> text 10 </span>
    <span style="border:2px solid red; margin-bottom:4px;"> text 11 </span>
    <span style="border:2px solid red; margin-bottom:4px;"> text 12 </span>
    <span style="border:2px solid red; margin-bottom:4px;"> text 18 </span>
    <span style="border:2px solid red; margin-bottom:4px;"> text 14 </span>
    <span style="border:2px solid red; margin-bottom:4px;"> text15 </span>
    <span style="border:2px solid red; margin-bottom:4px;"> text 16 </span>
    <span style="border:2px solid red; margin-bottom:4px;"> text 17 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: (I'm assuming you typo'ed the `margin-bttom` in your question as its correct in your code insert). However, give your `span` elements `display:inline-block;` and margin should start working. PS. if this is being used in a html email template, it is recommended to use non-shorthand css properties (ie. dont use `margin` use the 4 versions of `margin-XXXX`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give `display:inline-block;` to span, as span tag is inline element margin won't effect it.

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px;">
  <span> text 1 </span>
  <span> text 2 </span>
  <span> text 888888 888888 888 888  8  8888 8 8 888 888 8888 888  88888  8888 888 8888 8888 8888 </span> 
  <span>text 4</span>
  <span> text5 </span>
  <span> text 6 </span>
  <span> text 7 </span>
  <span> text 9 </span>
  <span> text 10 </span>
  <span>text 11</span>
  <span> text 12 </span>
  <span> text 18 </span>
  <span> text 14 </span>
  <span> text15 </span>
  <span> text 16 </span>
  <span> text 17 </span>
</div>
```